# How to compare two Hash Maps in Java

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, comparison

Hi I am working with HashMap in java and i have a scenario where i have to compare 2 HashMaps

```
HashMap1:
Key: BOF   Value: SAPF
Key: BOM   Value: SAPM
Key: BOL   Value: SAPL

HashMap2:
Key: BOF   Value: Data1
Key: BOL   Value: Data2
```

And after comparing these two hashmaps my resulting hashmap will contain the Key as a Value of First HashMap1 and Value as a Value of second HashMap2.

```
HashMap3:
Key: SAPF  Value: Data1
Key: SAPL  Value: Data2
```

Comment: Compare according to what? Keys? Values? Both?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just iterate on the keys of `HashMap1`, and for each key, check if it's present in `HashMap2`.
If it's present, add the values to `HashMap3` :

```
final Map<String, String> hm1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
hm1.put("BOF", "SAPF");
hm1.put("BOM", "SAPM");
hm1.put("BOL", "SAPL");

final Map<String, String> hm2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
hm2.put("BOF", "Data1");
hm2.put("BOL", "Data2");

final Map<String, String> hm3 = new HashMap<String, String>();

for (final String key : hm1.keySet()) {
    if (hm2.containsKey(key)) {
        hm3.put(hm1.get(key), hm2.get(key));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over the keys of the first map and put the values in your new map, if the second map has a value for the same key.

```
Map map3 = new HashMap();
for (Object key : map1.keySet()) {
    Object value2 = map2.get(key);
    if (value2 != null) {
        Object value1 = map1.get(key);
        map3.put(value1, value2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

HashMap has an method called `entrySet()` that returns an object that represents the content of the map as a set of key-value pairs.

```
public Set<Map.Entry<K,V>> entrySet()
```

You should iterate through that set using the keys to look up in the second map and then putting the results in the 'result set'.

I assume you have a established that the **values** in the first set will be unique OR you don't mind that entries might get overwritten in the output.

Notice that the iterator moves through the set in an unspecified order so if there are overwrites this method won't guarantee which values overwrite which other values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the keySets of both maps to intersect them using:

```
boolean     retainAll(Collection<?> c)
```

and then iterate using that intersection over the tho maps building your solution.